# Integer points of $y^2 = x^3 - 4x + 9$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to find analytically all the integer points of $y^2 = x^3 - 4x + 9$.
The integer solutions I found so far are

$\{-2, 3\}, \{0, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{7, 18\}, \{11, 36\}, \{646, 16419\}$

The first five are easy to find with modulo considerations, but how can I find $\{646, 16419\}$? How to prove there are no more solutions?

Comment: You have been around for eleven months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: That's right! I will be more careful next time

Comment: Are you aware you're formula is an elliptic curve? Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve provides some insight, particularly the sections on the group law and elliptic curves over rational numbers.

Comment: @StevenClark yes of course! I read this paper too on the solutions of a similar elliptic curve https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82666129.pdf but I wanted to know if it's possible to derive that result in a straightforward way. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

All integral points are given by
$$
(-2,\pm 3), (0,\pm 3), (2,\pm 3), (7,\pm 18),
(11,\pm 36), (646,\pm 16419)
$$
see the reference for the database in [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/7724/a/1).

Answer (score 2):

For your first question

> ,but how can I find $(646,16419)$?

There is an easy method using lines intersecting the curve $y^2 = x^3-4x+9.$
Given any two points on the curve, the unique line
they determine intersects the curve in another point.
In the case of the points $(2,3)$ and $(-2,-3)$
this third point is $(9/4,27/8)$. With this new point
and the point $(2,-3)$ the third point is $(646,16419).$

Your second question

> How to prove there are no more solutions?

is much harder. Perhaps descent methods may work here.

Answer (score 1):

In SageMath 8.0:

```
R.<x,y> = QQ[]
E = EllipticCurve(x^3-4*x+9-y^2)
E.integral_points(both_signs=true):
```

$$\eqalign{&[(-2 : -3 : 1),\cr
 &(-2 : 3 : 1),\cr
 &(0 : -3 : 1),\cr
 &(0 : 3 : 1),\cr
 &(2 : -3 : 1),\cr
 &(2 : 3 : 1),\cr
 &(7 : -18 : 1),\cr
 &(7 : 18 : 1),\cr
 &(11 : -36 : 1),\cr
 &(11 : 36 : 1),\cr
 &(646 : -16419 : 1),\cr
 &(646 : 16419 : 1)]}$$